# How has pair/couple ended up meaning both 2 and more in different languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, vocabulary

Consider the following examples from different languages:

> (en) The bridge has been built a **couple** years ago.
>
> (de) Das Problem ist größer als vor ein **paar** Jahren.
>
> (pl) Poznaliśmy się **parę** lat temu.
>
> (sv) Det tar ett **par** veckor.

... and I am sure there are other examples too.

Clearly the notion of pair/couple has become to mean more than two (I'd even argue in these sentences it would be a stretch to interpret it as "two or more", to me it sounds clearly as "more than two"). At the same time - in other contexts, in the same languages - the word 'pair' or similar means exactly 2.

How come several languages ended up with such (same!) ambiguity?
Moreover affecting involving different stems (~pair, ~couple)

Comment: By _with such ambiguity_ if you mean _with same ambiguity_ then the answer is cognates. They retain their semantics from before adoption, so these languages might have adopted the same word "with ambiguity"

Comment: There was a recent Language Hat blog post about English "a couple", based on a Lingua Franca article by Anne Curzan ("[A Couple of Thoughts](https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2018/01/22/a-couple-of-thoughts)"); the comments mention some other examples: [HOW MANY IS A COUPLE?](http://languagehat.com/how-many-is-a-couple)

Comment: Note that the quoted languages are in geographical proximity of each other and that there is a lot of contact between them. It may be a Sprachbund feature.

Comment: In Cantonese, loeng5 ('two') can also refer to more than two of something in an indefinite NP. I don't think it's as common as 'couple', though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a lexical gap, also borderline case of an accidental semantic gap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap#Semantic_gaps).

Simply put, there is a concept that is missing a word from the lexicon. Therefore the next best thing that is available, its immediate neighbour pours into that space and integrates its meaning.

In this case, on an imaginary scale, this would be along the lines of:

```
plenty > many > numerous > several > a few > more than two but not quite so many that we could call them a few or several > couple / pair (as in exactly two) > one / single
```

In this case, few and a couple overlap and allow for a choice in everyone's personal dictionary. So this has nothing to do with stems, it is based purely in semantics. Also exists in, say Hungarian, where the word `pár` has the same exact connotation meaning a couple (male and female of the same species) and also a few, more than two.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is an advantage in ambiguity. "Couple" means "about two", in the same way that "dozen" means "about twelve" and "score" means "about twenty". By contrast "two", "twelve" and "twenty" are exact quantities.

Comment: isnt OP's question also about how the ambiguity was the same in different languages as well?